# EF6 with localdb v13 underlying connection failed to open

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a simple console app with EF6, my PC has localdb v13 and when I try to connect to the EF database, I get this error

```
{"Cannot open database \"NinjaDomain.DataModel.NinjaContext\" requested by the login. The login failed.\r\nLogin failed for user 'xx\\xx.yy'."}
```

this is the app.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2" />
  </startup>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

Comment: I am admin on sql server local db btw...

Comment: C:\WINDOWS\system32> sqllocaldb.exe create
La instancia "MSSQLLocalDB" de LocalDB se creó con la versión 13.0.1100.286.

Comment: Add the connection string to your app.config in your AppData

Comment: its a console app, there is no app_data please explain further

Comment: You'd typically expect to see an entry in the `connectionStrings` section of your App.config. e.g. something like `<add name="NinjaContext" connectionString="data source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;initial catalog=NinjaDomain.DataModel.NinjaContext;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />`. Where are you setting the connection string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is does not matter Console app might also have an App.config, normally if you have installed EF from Package Manager Console like that:

```
install-package entityframework
```

The app.config will be automatically added to your project file.

This is the default connection string, if the do not have it the app.config (related to EF v 6.1.3)

```
"Data Source=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Initial Catalog=MyConsoleApplication.Program+MyDbContext;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True"
```

Below, I have changed the app.config (If you do not have you can just add it to your project) and I have provided the connection string

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1" />
  </startup>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DatabaseConnectionString"
         connectionString="Integrated Security=SSPI; Initial Catalog=UsersDatabase5; Data Source=.\;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

You should pass the connection string to the DbContext constructor with 'name' keyword like that:

```
using (var myDbContext = new MyDbContext("name=" + "DatabaseConnectionString"))
{
 ....
```

I have used the normal SQL Server in my app.config example:

```
Data Source=.\;
```

You can change it:

```
Data Source=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;
```

or just check your SQL Server instance name (use SSM or command line).